# What does this error message mean?

Tags: errors, lyx

I am a Lyx user and sometimes receive this error message,

[The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.]

What does this mean and what should I do not to get this error?
(But anyway, I got the correct result! seems weird)

Comment: What you posted is not the error message itself but the help text for it. The error message itself is one line above. Most probably it's just a typo.

Comment: The only way to learn about the error is to dig in to specific cases. The next time you see it, please post a minimal example .lyx file: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: The quite general -- and perhaps not very useful -- answer for how to avoid it, is to not use macros that are not defined (by LaTeX, or yourself, or the packages and documentclass used). For example if you were to write `\snafu` in an ERT in a standard document you'd get that error I think, because the macro `\snafu` is not defined in a standard document. But what happened in your specific example is impossible to say without an example, as scottkosty asked for.

Comment: The error mean that  you (or LyX) have written a command that does not exist for LaTeX.   For instance, some like `\foo` is an  undefined control sequence  except if you type first some like `\def\foo{baz}` (in a ERT or the LaTeX preamble).   In practice mean that is a command of some package that was not loaded, or you changed to the  wrong class (e.g. leaving a `\chapter` in an article),  or you reused code without know what are you doing, or you misspelled some  command (e.g. typing `\oclor` instead of `\color`).